# C# & ASP.NET MVC - The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am creating a project. First, I created all my models and data access in one project. However I now moved them into separate projects like this:

[image]

I updated all the import and for the models it works fine however when I try and update the imports for the `ApplicationDBContext` which is stored in the `DataAccess` project it seems as though it's not there and I get an error that it could not be found.

I tried to add project reference to the `DataAccess`, but every time I do the tick box gets removed when I reopen the project references.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Make sure DataAccess does not have reference to web project, this might be one of the issues. Another options is to restart Visual Studio (and optionally remove `.vs` folder). As a last resort i sometimes modify csproj files manually (just copy one of existing references in csproj xml and change project name).

Comment: Yep, it was linked to the web project as soon as i unlinked it. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to investigate and actions:

1. Sometimes Visual Studio does not warns about circular dependencies, so make sure DataAccess project does not have reference to web project
2. Another option is to restart Visual Studio (and optionally remove .vs folder).
3. As a last resort I sometimes modify `csproj` files manually (just copy one of existing references in `csproj` XML and change project name).